# Find Minimum Games

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A player has played unknown number of games. We know the average score(=N,which is a rational number) of the player (sum of scores in all the games / no. of games). Find the minimum number of games the player should have played to achieve that average.

The player can score any non-negative integer score in a game.

Comment: The lowest-terms denominator comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $N=\frac pq$, with $p,q\in\mathbb N$, $q\neq 0$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$, he must have played as least $q$ games.
**Prove:**
It is possible when $q$ games have been played: If he won (scored $1$) $p$ times and lost $q-p$ times (score $0$), the average score is
$$\frac{p\cdot 1+(p-q)\cdot 0}q=\frac pq$$
$N=\frac pq$ can't be reached when there are fewer than $q$ games played. Suppose that $0<t<q$ is the number of games played and $s\in \mathbb N$ is the score. Then, we have
$$
\frac pq=N=\frac st
$$
It follows that $pt=qs$. We know that $q|qs$, so $q|pt$. Because $\gcd(p,q)=1$, we get $q|t$. But now, we know that $t=0$ or $|t|\geq q$. Both of these possibilities contradict $0<t<q$, so $q$ is the smallest number of possible games that has been played.

Answer (score 0):

Just write $N$ as $\frac{p}{q}$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(p,q) = 1$. Basic number theory then gives $q$ as a solution to your question.